# What is the probability that the minimum of _X1_, _X2_ and _X3_ is larger than 1?

Tags: statistics

Hello I found a problem on statistics which make me a bit confused. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Let *X1*, *X2*, *X3* be independent random variables following exponential
distribution with parameter *θ*=$5$. What is the probability that the minimum of *X1*,
*X2* and *X3* is larger than $1$?

Comment: Please provide thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Also, did you mean parameter $\theta = .5$? That makes more sense.

Comment: i think it is θ=$5$

Comment: I found there are 2 possible methods but they give 2 different answers.

Comment: $\theta = .5$ gives $3.059023e-07$. That's why I am suspicious. It might be $\theta = .5$.

Comment: but why can't I use 1 minus the probability that all the Xi from 0 to 1?

Comment: these 2 methods give different answers... but I can't explain that

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have the minimum be smaller than something. That is hard to calculate. You need to have it be larger than something. That is easier to calculate.

Comment: oh thanks a lot!

Comment: Your suggestion to use $1$ minus the probability that they are all $\le 1$ is not right. For $1$ minus the probability they are all $\le 1$ counts, among others, the case where the values are $2$, $0.7$, and $3$, and in this case the minimum is not greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way is, if $M$ is the minimum of the three, then
\begin{align*}
P(M>1) &= P(X_1>1,X_2>1,X_3>1)\\
&= P(X_1>1)P(X_2>1)P(X_3>1)\tag{1}\\
&= e^{-5}e^{-5}e^{-5}\\
&=3.059023e-07,
\end{align*}
where (1) is true because of independence.